# conditionally include instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Video model which supports multiple third party video services such as Youtube, Vimeo and Livestream.

A user creates a new video and selects the service and the id for that video.

In my video model at the moment my methods have a lot of case statements depending on which service was used.

E.g.

```
class Video

  def video_duration
    case service
      when 'Vimeo'
        Time.at(duration).utc.strftime("%-l:%M:%S")
      when 'Livestream'
       'Ongoing'
    end
  end

end
```

Ideally i would like to have a module for each service with instance methods which can be included into the model depending on which video service was selected. Can this be done?

I considered inheritance although this seems a pain as it changes how every thing is referenced in views e.g. different class names, routes expected, etc. none of which i need.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "inheritance although this seems a pain"... It's not.  Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is the best way as noted by Billy & Hitham. But this didn't solve the problem of all the various changes that happen in views such as routes, CSS class names, forms_for. These are generated based on a models model_name class method. This can be overridden in the subclass as such

```
class VimeoVideo < Video

  def self.model_name
    Video.model_name
  end

end
```

This produces:

```
VimeoVideo.model_name

#<ActiveModel::Name:0x007f9106973800 @name="Video", @klass=Video(id: integer, title: string, .....), @singular="video", @plural="videos", @element="video", @human="Video", @collection="videos", @param_key="video", @i18n_key=:video, @route_key="videos", @singular_route_key="video"
```

Rendering a collection of videos still requires been more specific as such (rather than render @videos ):

```
<%= render partial: 'video', collection: @videos, as: :video %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use inheritance is the best solution, as Hitham also said.

Writing controllers/views has no difference because you are dealing with instances, not classes.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  def service
    ''
  end
end

class VimeoViedo < Video
  def service
    Time.at(duration).utc.strftime("%-l:%M:%S")
  end
end

class LiveStream < Video
  def service
    'ongoing'
  end
end

# Controller
def show
  klass = params[:type].constantize
  @video = klass.find(params[:id])
end

# View
<%= @video.service %>
```